# Some of the resources are not accessible via URL

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I have troubles loading binary file from resource in Qt 5.3.2 on Windows using all MVSC2013 32-bit, MinGW 4.8.2 32-bit compiler and GCC 4.9 for Android

I have two resource files. They are both in the root directory of the project as well as all the resources. The first one, qml.qrc, is:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>ScoreText.qml</file>
        <file>ControlButton.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and resource.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>sound.wav</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And I have in my project file:

```
QT += qml quick widgets multimedia
RESOURCES += qml.qrc resource.qrc
```

I can read the QML no problem, but the "sound" file misbehaves.

```
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resource);

    QFile q_file;
    q_file.setFileName(":/sound.wav"); // works
    // q_file.setFileName("qrc:/sound.wav"); does not work
    // q_file.setFileName("qrc:///sound.wav"); does not work
    q_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if (!q_file.exists()) 
        qCritical() << "File does not exist.";

    return app.exec();
}
```

I init the resource as suggested here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library and I tried loading both in the style "qrc:///" as suggested here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html and the style "qrc:/" as suggested here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html , but only the non-URL way (":/") works. The "main.qml" is no problem though, only the waveform file...

Any suggestions?

Comment: `QDir::setSearchpath( "qrc", ":/" );`

Comment: I had to change it to 
QDir::setSearchPaths("qrc", QStringList(":/") );
but it works, seems kinda hack-ish, though :)

Comment: It's not a hack. You need to read Qt documentation.

Comment: Could you please point to specific part of the documentation you have in mind? In the parts about Resource system I can not see anything relevant to your comment, quite the contrary - "For example, the file path :/images/cut.png or the URL qrc:///images/cut.png would give access to the cut.png file," - suggest that no additional code is needed.

Comment: Read documentation about `QDir::setSearchpath`. And about path aliases.